# Get a remote post ID via API given URL

Tags: rest-api, api, wp-api, content-restriction

**Given you have a URL, how can you get the post ID of a post on a remote WordPress site?**

As far as I can tell, you would have to:

```
HTTP GET /wp-json/v2/posts
```

And then look for your URL, but the problem is that this endpoint will only return 100 results by default.

I don't want to have to download the ENTIRE content of a site just to find the post ID of a given URL. In V1 you could submit a query, but I think that's been depreciated. Any better ways to do this?

Comment: If you know the slug (based on the URL), then you can use the `slug` parameter - `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=hello-world`. Or you could create a custom endpoint.. if you've got control over the WordPress site.

Comment: This worked! Sally put it in the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Posts [endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) accepts a `slug` parameter when querying for posts, so if you can get the slug from the URL, then you can make request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=<slug>`.

So if the URL is `http://example.com/hello-world/` and you know the slug is `hello-world`, then for example in JavaScript, you can do something like:

```js
fetch( 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=hello-world' )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( posts => console.log( posts[0].id ) );
```

Or you could create a custom endpoint.. if you've got control over the WordPress site. See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for more details.